# C# syntax and creating UUIDs

Tags: c#, javascript, syntax

Okay, .NET newbie here, so bear with me. I'm trying to create a unique identifier for the selector that the JS function is triggering. This has to be done in C#, so I'm using the UUID method to get this done. However, it's not working and I'm thinking that my syntax is probably incorrect or I need some Out.WriteLines around the javascript elements. Can someone help me? I'm stumped and haven't got a clue where I went wrong. (Either way, it's not outputting the value on the end of #jquery_jplayer_(value).) I just need pointed in the right direction, or maybe a tutorial. Thanks in advance.

```
 case "video":
    string thumbnailImage = "";
    if (contentBlock["video_thumbnail"] != "") {
        thumbnailImage = contentBlock["video_thumbnail"];
    }

    string uuid = "videoPlayerIdentifier"; 
    %>
        <div class="videoPlayer">
            <a class="video" href="#<%=contentBlock["video_id"]%>"><img height="94" width="172" alt="Play video" src="<%=thumbnailImage%>" style="float:right;"/></a> 
            <a id="<%=contentBlock["video_id"]%>anchor" name="<%=contentBlock["video_id"]%>anchor"></a>
            <%=contentBlock["video_caption"]%>
            <ul class="square"> 
                <li><a class="video" href="#<%=contentBlock["video_id"]%>">Play Video</a></li>
            </ul>        
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $("#jquery_jplayer_<%=videoPlayerIdentifier%>").jPlayer({
                    ready: function () {
                        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                            mp4: "<%=contentBlock["video_mp4"]%>",
                            webm: "<%=contentBlock["video_webm"]%>",
                            ogv: "<%=contentBlock["video_ogv"]%>",
                            poster: "<%=contentBlock["video_still"]%>"
                        });
                    },
                    swfPath: "/video/",
                    supplied: "mp4, webm, ogv"
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: `$("#jquery_jplayer_<%=uuid%>")` isn't the value in the variable `uuid`?

Comment: Yeah, I think I have it backwards. I also need to call the Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); method and then define the string with that method. (I just got called out on this by a coworker. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mathew points out, I think you've mixed up your variable name with it's value. If you want your variable to be a unique identifier though, you could replace your initialization with

```
string uuid = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

Comment: I think you're right. Now I have a new issue. The selectors have to be unique and this method didn't quite fit the bill. I'm using jPlayer.js and it needs a numeric value in order to play the videos correctly. We thought this might work, but it's looking as though the script is being picky about the values. I could do an increment counter, but again I'm a C# newbie and not quite sure how to get this going.

Comment: Do you mean the id-selector `"#jquery_jplayer_<%=videoPlayerIdentifier%>"`? That refers to an _empty_ div tag with the corresponding id property, e.g. you need the following code in your html document: `<div id="jquery_jplayer_<%=videoPlayerIdentifier%>"></div>`. See http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/ and http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-constructor for more information.